# Entity Framework: Disposing a single entity in the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am updating an old application which uses EF4 and the functions Load() and Refresh() extensively because it creates the context only once.

At one place I need the newest data of a table from the DB. So far such tasks were solved using Refresh(). For this particular table (1000000 entries) this takes way too long so I decided to dispose and recreate the context. The problem I have is I don't know if I create any negative side effects this way.

Is there a way to simply dispose that particular table? I can't Refresh() because it takes too long and I am not sure if I can recreate the context.

Comment: Do you have considered to create a new context only for that task?

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. This indeed is a good idea but then I don't have the newest data in the original context.

Comment: Honestly, you can expect negative impact on performance with big contexts, because they are designed as Unit of Work instances. But the point of mnieto still holds: you can create an empty context to look for this entry. if it exists, you could simply attach it to your big context (after disposing the other), or at least put it in your ChangeTracker.

Comment: After querying, the new context will have a different snapshot of the big table than the original one. How can I move the table of the second context to the original context? Attaching doesn't seem to work because it needs an IEntityWithKey and the table is an ObjectSet.